# How to toggle line's visibility from Dataframe plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a panda dataframe that contains around 8 lines that needs to be plotted. I want to have a clear view of those lines as it can get messy with so many lines intercepting. I saw a [solution](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html) using legend picking to toggle the line's visibility, but this requires to match the legend line to the actual line in the graph.

Is there a way to get those lines or either other way to toggle its visibility?

As for my code, after preparing the dataframe, I'm simply plotting:

```
df.plot(figsize=(20, 8), fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You might need to provide us with this data

Comment: You may want to consider using plotly express for this. Plotly  line plots automatically provide such interactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `df.plot()` returns an `axes.Axes` object, which has a `.get_lines()` method. As said on the tin, that returns the plotted lines.

Here’s the example you quote rewritten around a `pd.DataFrame.plot`:

```
ax = df.plot(figsize=(20, 8), fontsize=16)
ax.set_title('Click on legend line to toggle line on/off')
leg = ax.legend(fancybox=True, shadow=True)

lined = {}  # Will map legend lines to original lines.
for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), ax.get_lines()):
    legline.set_picker(True)  # Enable picking on the legend line.
    lined[legline] = origline


def on_pick(event):
    # On the pick event, find the original line corresponding to the legend
    # proxy line, and toggle its visibility.
    legline = event.artist
    origline = lined[legline]
    visible = not origline.get_visible()
    origline.set_visible(visible)
    # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
    # have been toggled.
    legline.set_alpha(1.0 if visible else 0.2)
    ax.get_figure().canvas.draw()

ax.get_figure().canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()
```

I find however that the the click box for the lines in the legend is rather small, so maybe you’ll need to click around a little to find out where it is (I have to aim for the upper edge of the legend’s lines).